# Image at bottom in every column on amcharts

Tags: image, charts, bar-chart, amcharts

I've tried to gather information about if it is possible to put a different image located at the bottom of every column in a 100% stacked bar chart.

I've seen that is possible to modify some attributes of category labels and put images just above every bar as http://www.amcharts.com/demos/column-chart-images-top/ but I need just the opposite.

In other words, I want to make the base of the column has an image loaded, replacing x axis and category label.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Category axis does not allow using images in place of category labels.

There's also no way to make the custom bullets from graphs "trickle" outside plot area.

What you **can** do is to drop those custom icons right down just above category axis line.

To do that you will need:

1) Add additional fields to your data that would contain all zero values.
2) Add a separate graph that would use those fields and display custom bullets.
3) Make the "bullet graph" non-stackable ([`stackable: false`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmGraph#stackable)), not clustered ([`clustered: false`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmGraph#clustered)), and generally invisible ([`visibleInLegend: false`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmGraph#visibleInLegend), [`fillAlphas: 0`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmGraph#fillAlphas), [`lineAlpha: 0`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmGraph#lineAlpha), [`showBalloon: false`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmGraph#showBalloon))

Here's a working example:

```js
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
  "type": "serial",
  "theme": "light",
  "dataProvider": [{
    "name": "John",
    "points": 35022,
    "color": "#7F8DA9",
    "zero": 0,
    "bullet": "//www.amcharts.com/lib/3/images/0.gif"
  }, {
    "name": "Damon",
    "points": 65456,
    "color": "#FEC514",
    "zero": 0,
    "bullet": "//www.amcharts.com/lib/3/images/1.gif"
  }, {
    "name": "Patrick",
    "points": 45724,
    "color": "#DB4C3C",
    "zero": 0,
    "bullet": "//www.amcharts.com/lib/3/images/2.gif"
  }, {
    "name": "Mark",
    "points": 13654,
    "color": "#DAF0FD",
    "zero": 0,
    "bullet": "//www.amcharts.com//lib/3/images/3.gif"
  }],
  "valueAxes": [{
    "maximum": 80000,
    "minimum": 0,
    "axisAlpha": 0,
    "dashLength": 4,
    "position": "left"
  }],
  "startDuration": 1,
  "graphs": [{
    "balloonText": "<span style='font-size:13px;'>[[category]]: <b>[[value]]</b></span>",
    "colorField": "color",
    "fillAlphas": 0.8,
    "lineAlpha": 0,
    "type": "column",
    "valueField": "points"
  }, {
    "showBalloon": false,
    "bulletOffset": 16,
    "bulletSize": 34,
    "customBulletField": "bullet",
    "fillAlphas": 0,
    "lineAlpha": 0,
    "type": "column",
    "visibleInLegend": false,
    "clustered": false,
    "stackable": false,
    "valueField": "zero"
  }],
  "categoryField": "name",
  "categoryAxis": {
    "axisAlpha": 0,
    "gridAlpha": 0,
    "tickLength": 0
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="http://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/serial.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/themes/light.js"></script>
<div id="chartdiv" style="width: 100%; height: 200px;"></div>
```

Additionally, if you don't need the text labels on the category axis, you can set it's [`labelsEnabled: false`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/CategoryAxis#labelsEnabled) property.